# how to kill the activity streaming HLS on Android4

Tags: android, android-emulator, http-live-streaming, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I made an app which which launches with an Activity which is essentially a list of videos. When the user clicks on one of the options that video is streamed via HLS(Apple's http live streaming) in another Activity. Now when I press the back button, home button etc, the activity is not finished and the video plays in the background. All i want to do is whenever somebody navigates out of the app for whatever reason, i want to kill that activity. How can that be done.

code i use for hls streaming:

```
MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            m.setDataSource("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8");
        m.prepare();
        m.start();}
        catch(Exception e){}
```

thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for killing an activity you can do

```
yourClassName.this.finish();
this.finish();
finish();
```

hope this helps

Comment: add this in onstop, so that it is killed when someone moves out of the app

Comment: adding to nandeesh`s comment. you can make a new Class that extends Application and then in that class override the desired super class, and do your thing

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed for back button, or  onStop for home button click. On that methods put

```
m.stop();
m.release();
```